# How to find out if I have a savings account already?

Tags: united-states, savings

I grew up in an awkward position. I never was told much about finances or anything having to do with them.
When my stepfather died, my mother said something about savings accounts for my step brother and I. 
Now, 5 years later, I could really use the money if there ever really was any. However, I have no clue about how to check if this savings account actually exists, much less how to access it.

If anyone can somehow give me advice, it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

I live and grew up in Florida (never lived anywhere else).

Comment: Does your mother know anything about it now?

Comment: Go to every single bank you can walk/drive to and present your ID. It's cumbersome but if you could really use the money then it's a small hurdle. I honestly feel like you must be the prince of Nigeria something but Good Luck anyways! P.S. Please let me know as soon as you need $500 to cover taxes/fees to get the money out of the account so that I may profit in the wealth! :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you know what bank your parents used, call them and ask. (Or you might have to go there and show id). Chances are if such an account exists, it would be at the same bank.

You can also search for unclaimed property. [Here's the information link for Florida](http://www.myfloridacfo.com/sitePages/services/flow.aspx?ut=Unclaimed%20Property).

Answer (score 5):

If you're in the UK, there's a free service [here](https://www.mylostaccount.org.uk/) that lets you trace lost bank accounts. If you're in a different country, try Googling to see if that country has a similar service.

Comment: The same service exists in the US if you search through public record it should be able to show you any history of bank accounts that are in your name. The trouble would be seeing if the accounts are tied to your SSN or under a UTMA account. But hopefully that at least gives you a start on your search.